# recount value in dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like

```
result =[{'a': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]
```

Now I want to recount the value of these dictionaries. For example, 'a' is subtring of `'ar'` and `len(a)/len(ar)=1/2` so `{'a':5}` turn to `{'a':5+10/2}`.
Also, 'a' is substring of 'ade' and len(a)/len(ade)=1/3 . Finally, it should be      {'a': 5+10/2+10/3} . So how can I solve this problem without using for method?

I found that I can turn this result to a dictionary in the previous step but I still need to use for method.

Comment: No matter what your approach is, loop will be used internally because computer does not have any magic tricks.

Comment: Your definition of "recounting" is at best vague. Please update your question so we would know, what is going on here.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I want to find a better solution because I have no idea about how large the list will be.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski This result is returned from another API using for word count. But my leader wants me to do other things so I need to count the number of word appearance again by using this list.

Comment: So you are looking for an efficient search structure to find superstrings? Are you looking for just a result? What have you tried so far? Do you have a size estimate or scalability requirement?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have no idea about how large the list will be. So I want to find a solution without using for method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output is not clear ('ar' Vs. 'ade'?), but I'd suggest use the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result =[{'a': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]

res = defaultdict(list)

for h in result:
  key = list(h.keys())[0]
  val = list(h.values())[0]
  key_f = key[0]
  size = len(key)
  print(size)
  res[key_f].append(val/size)
```

This steps produces:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [5.0, 5.0, 3.3333333333333335], 'b': [4.0], 'c': [3.0]})
```

Then iterate transforming values to the sum of the list:

```
for k, v in res.items():
  res[k] = sum(v)


print(dict(res))
#=> {'a': 13.333333333333334, 'b': 4.0, 'c': 3.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result =[{'a': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]

relation = []
valor = {}

for example in range(0, len(result)):
    for example2 in list(result[example].keys()):
        for examplex in range(0, len(result)):
            if examplex != example and example2[0] in list(result[examplex].keys())[0] and list(result[examplex].keys())[0] not in relation:
                #print('True')
                relation.append(list(result[examplex].keys())[0])
                print(list(result[examplex].keys())[0], list(result[examplex].values())[0])
                if example2[0] not in valor:
                    print("No existe, se crea como un valor nuevo.")
                    valor[example2[0]] = list(result[example].values())[0] + list(result[examplex].values())[0] / len(list(result[examplex].keys())[0])
                elif example2 in valor:
                    print("Existe, se esta modificando.")
                    valor[example2[0]] += list(result[examplex].values())[0] / len(list(result[examplex].keys())[0])

print(valor[example2[0]])

'''Here you can iterate with for :) valor, 1 hour for do it 0_0'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    result =[{'a': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]
    dd ={}
    v=0
    for i in result:
        key=i.keys()[0]
        if key.__contains__('a'):
            l=i[key]/len(key)
            v = v+l
    dd={'a':v}
    #dd ={'a': 13}
```

Comment: But if this doesn't work when I have 'abe' in this dictionary. I want to find a general solution

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

- `round(number[, ndigits])` - The round() method returns the floating point number rounded off to the given ndigits digits after the decimal point.
- [enumerate(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) - Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration.

**Ex.**

```
result =[{'a': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]

for index,x in enumerate(result):
    key = list(x.keys())[0]
    # get all key substring dictionary
    subtring_value = {list(result[y].keys())[0] : list(result[y].values())[0]
                       for y in range(index+1,len(result)) if key in list(result[y].keys())[0]}
    if len(subtring_value) > 0:
        total = list(x.values())[0]
        total = total+ sum(v/len(k) for k,v in subtring_value.items())
        x[key] = round(total,2)

print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'a': 13.33}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

result = [{'a': 5}, {'b': 4}, {'c': 3}, {'ar': 10}, {'ade': 10}]

out = {}
for v1, v2 in product(result, repeat=2):
    i1 = [*v1][0]
    i2 = [*v2][0]
    if i1 in i2:
        out.setdefault(i1, []).append((i2, v2[i2]))

result = []
for k, v in out.items():
    s = 0
    for (vv, cnt) in v:
        s += cnt * (len(k) /  len(vv))
    result.append({k : s})

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[{'a': 13.333333333333332}, {'b': 4.0}, {'c': 3.0}, {'ar': 10.0}, {'ade': 10.0}]
```